# Wildcard within the jboss-all.xml file when specifying dependencies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

When specifying dependencies on a 3rd party ear within the jboss-all.xml file, is it possible to utilize a wildcard or a technique to avoid having to update the file for each version number change like the third dependency listed below?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
        <dependency name="app1-1.2.3.ear" />
        <dependency name="app2-2.5.3.1.ear" />
        <dependency name="app3-2.*.ear" />
    </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```